# Tracking a file by identity on Linux

Tags: linux, file, filesystems

On OS X, there is an API to create a "bookmark" for a given file on disk, which will track its target even if it is moved or renamed. An OS X application could then serialise the bookmark, store it by whatever means it wants, and at some later date—perhaps after being quit and re-launched—deserialise the bookmark and resolve the file path from it.

Does anything comparable exist for Linux?

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify

I guess that inotify is what you want.
With inotify, you can monitor following events for a file:

```
IN_ACCESS - read of the file
IN_MODIFY - last modification
IN_ATTRIB - attributes of file change
IN_OPEN - open of file
IN_CLOSE_WRITE - sent when a file opened for writing is closed
IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE - sent when a file opened not for writing is closed
IN_MOVED_FROM and IN_MOVED_TO - when the file is moved or renamed
IN_DELETE - a file/directory deleted
IN_CREATE - a file in a watched directory is created
IN_DELETE_SELF - file monitored is deleted
```

Comment: inotify only works while a process is running, no? I don't see any way to persist an inotify instance across process relaunches.

Comment: @NickHutchinson Yes. if you want to log events for given file within your own application, it cannot be a solution. How about make some monitor daemon with inotify? The monitor daemon logs events for given files and your own application use that log information. Sounds awkward?

Comment: It does sound awkward, but it seems to be the only way.